# How can I hide the horizontal line in the login form of the ionic HTML mobile UI?

Tags: android, html, angular, ionic-framework, mobile

I have tried to design this login form on the HTML ionic mobile UI. Everything seems good. But I don't want that horizontal line that comes in between the Forgot password label and the LOGIN button.How can I hide it?

Login.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <!-- <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar> -->
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <img src="assets/imgs/homeconn_header.png" class="page-login" />

  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email address</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="vm.username" placeholder="Email address" formControlName="username" tabindex="1" (keyup)="moveFocus($event,password, false)"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors && (form.controls.username.dirty || form.controls.username.touched)">
      <p class="validation-align"  *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors?.required">Email address is required</p>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="vm.password" placeholder="Password"  formControlName="password" tabindex="2" #password (keyup)="moveFocus($event,submitbutton, true)"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="error-message" *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors && (form.controls.password.dirty || form.controls.password.touched)">
      <p class="validation-password-align" *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.required">Password is required</p>
    </div>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label (click)="forgotpasswrd()" class="btn-style">Forgot Password?</ion-label>
    </ion-item>


<div class="btn-submit">
    <button ion-button name="loginbutton" (click)="login()" tabindex="3" #submitbutton>Login</button>
</div>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

My login.scss file

```
{
text-align: center;
}
.forgotposition{
    width:"100%";
    text-align: "right";
}

.btn-style{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: end;

}

.login-btn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
}
.btn-submit{
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
 }
 .validation-align{

    margin-right: 35%;


 }
 .validation-password-align{

    margin-right: 43%;

  }
```

page login:

[image: page-login]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give no-lines on `<ion-item>`

```
<ion-item no-lines>
    <ion-label (click)="forgotpasswrd()" class="btn-style">
        Forgot Password? 
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

[**Working code here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-y2wqvb?file=app/app.html)

[Offical Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/)